# htaccess redirection subdomain

Tags: .htaccess

I want to redirect feedback.domain.de to www.domain.de/de/abc/cde.html via htaccess.

My current htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.de$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.de/$1 [L,R=301]
```

SO, I thought just to add:

```
redirect 301 feedback.domain.de www.domain.de/de/abc/cde.html
```

but it doesn't work. If i try to open feedback.domain.de it redirects to www.domain.de

I know this is a very easy question but I don't how solve it in htaccess :-(

The result I want is:

```
domain.de -> www.domain.de/de/index.html
www.domain.de -> www.domain.de/de/index.html

domain.de/de/example.html -> www.domain.de/de/example.html
etc...

feedback.domain.de -> www.domain.de/de/feed.html
```

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

The `Redirect` directive only accept a path relative to the root path (for example */my-path*) and won't match on the host part of the URL.

Try this (**note that here I assume you want to redirect domain.de to www.domain.de and not *all* subdomains**):

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect feedback.domain.de to http://www.domain.de/de/abc/cde.html
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^feedback\.domain\.de$
RewriteRule . http://www.domain.de/de/abc/cde.html [L,R=301] 

# Redirect domain.de to www.domain.de
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.de$
RewriteRule . http://www.domain.de/$0 [L,R=301]
```

### Updated answer (2013-03-18):

```
# Redirect feedback.domain.de to http://www.domain.de/de/abc/cde.html
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^feedback\.(domain\.(de))$
RewriteRule .+ http://www.%1/%2/feed.html [L,R=301] 

# domain.de -> www.domain.de/de
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(domain\.(de))$
RewriteRule .+ http://www.%1/%2/$0 [L,R=301] 

# www.domain.de/de -> www.domain.de/de/index.html
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.(de)$
RewriteRule ^%1/?$ index.html [L,R=301]
```

Comment: hmm seems it doesnt work :( but i changed my plans. the result i want is:

domain.de -> www.domain.de/de/index.html /-/

www.domain.de -> www.domain.de/de/index.html /-/

feedback.domain.de -> www.domain.de/de/feed.html .... may you help me?